# How can I make Ubuntu my main OS on a Chromebook?

Tags: 14.04, opengl, chromebook, chromeos

I was recently gifted a Samsung Chromebook. I want to completely delete Chrome OS and make Ubuntu 14.04.1 my main operating system.

When I upgraded 12.04 to 14.04.1 from a standard download, as usual I had to restart my computer, but when I shut down Ubuntu all it does is shut down Ubuntu 14.04.1 and take me back to Chrome OS. Then I have to open a Chrome OS terminal via <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type `shell` then enter. And to get into Ubuntu I have to type `sudo startunity`. This used to work, but now when I do it I get this:

```
Welcome to crosh, the Chrome OS developer shell.

If you got here by mistake, don't panic!  Just close this tab and carry on.

Type 'help' for a list of commands.

crosh> shell
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

/usr/bin/Xephyr: error while loading shared libraries: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
chronos@localhost / $
```

I know that this is stating that I don’t have Ubuntu’s GL Open libraries.

- How can I wipe out chrome OS?
- How do I get the GL Open library if I cannot access Ubuntu?
- How can I get back into by beloved Ubuntu and make that the one and only OS on this computer?

Answer (score 1):

Simply updating crouton to the latest version should solve this problem. As for completely getting rid of Chrome OS, I would look into Chrubuntu. It allows you to dual boot Chrome OS and Ubuntu, allowing you to specify the hard disk space for each. You also have the option of installing any other Linux variant via a bootable USB stick. In addition, newer chromebooks have the option to boot via SEABios, allowing you to use the full Linux kernel and not the one provided by Chrome OS, so investigating this further would definitely be worth your while.

Answer (score 0):

Updating messes up the chroot on the chromebook. It thinks its loading precise, but then you updated to Ubuntu 14.04, so precise does not exist anymore on your chromebook. If you don't mind going out and back in dev mode, then do it. But if you do mind, run "sudo delete-chroot precise".